# Sort and structure some address data in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string, mobile

I have an app that calls to a server and gets a long string of data returned. The data is a list of addresses as in the example here:

```
2133664:American Taxi Dispatch, Inc:Mount Prospect:834 E RAND RD|2133665:Walmart:Mount Prospect:930 Mount Prospect Plaza|
```

The data is, a unique identifier, The title, the city, and the street address.

I need to first know how to traverse this data so that I can separate the identifier, title, city and street. I am also looking for a recommended data structure that I can use to tie all the information together. I will be adding the titles to a `NSMutableArray` so I can display them in a `UIPickerView`. Then the user will need to select one and the entire address must be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you're data is separated by `:`, what you need to do is to split each line on this character:

```
NSString* line = @"2133664:American Taxi Dispatch, Inc:Mount Prospect:834 E RAND RD|2133665:Walmart:Mount Prospect:930 Mount Prospect Plaza|"
NSArray* components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSString entryId = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString name = [components objectAtIndex:1];
NSString address = [components objectAtIndex:2];
// etc ...
```

You can use these components to build an object with fields for entryId, name, address. When displaying the item you use name, and when the item is selected you access the address field.

Comment: ok thats what I was looking for. Now do you recommend a structured way to store it so that the data is linked together. for example the title is linked to is corresponding address info?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go.